# Choosing the right datastructure with QPair and QString

Tags: c++, qt

I want to store a QPair and QString, or in other words I want to store three values for each index (int, int, String). I chose a QMap for this purpose which worked out okay, where the QString serves as a key and the QPair as the value.

So far I have only iterated through the QMap, but the problem arises when I want to look up one of the keys (QString). When I use `myQMap.key(myQPair)` the string returned is blank (I know the string I want isn't blank).

SO the question is how can I look up the QString by just using a QPair as argument? Could the QPair work as key? As far as I have understood, that's not gonna work.

Comment: There is an error in your code. While it would be slow, QMap should be able to do that reverse-lookup just fine. The behaviour you describe for `QMap::key` would only happen if either: 1. You didn't have a key-value pair with the value of myQPair, or 2. You had mistakenly inserted a key-value pair with a blank string for the key, and the value of myQPair.

Comment: Hmm, okay. I'll debug that to see. But just to clarify; is it possible to look up a QString with a QPair as value/key?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. All the necessary operators for being a key are defined for QString and QPair<int,int>. The limitation of QMap is that value to key lookups will take linear time (much slower than the log(n) of key to value lookups). Thus, if you need to do lookups in both directions quickly, you need a different data structure.

Comment: So, the answers are right to suggest that data structure change. However, the problem driving you to switch these things was not that it's too slow, but that your attempt was fundamentally not working. That indicates you're doing something wrong in the code you're describing (since what you're describing _should_ work).

Comment: Yep, you were right. The time pair I used as argument was wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `std::map` like object can use the value as a key, that defeats the purpose of it.

What you need is a `boost::bimap` ([docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html)).

Comment: But the person is using Qt.

Comment: @Bruce And Qt has no support for that functionality. `Boost::bimap` is header only with an extremely permissive license, there's reason to not use it.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want a map like data structure that works both ways; you want to look up a `QPair<int,int>` using a `QString` as key and you want to look up a `QString` using a `QPair<int,int>` as key.

There is no class in Qt that provides this functionality. So either you have to implement this yourself (there are many ways), or you can use [boost::bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating two maps.